# Cloud Dataflow reading/writing to/from bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have just started learning how to use some Google Cloud Products.
I am currently busy with Cloud Dataflow.
I decided to start writing simple program.
It does nothing more than reading from Bigquery table and than writing to another table.

The job is failing.

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<TableRow> data = p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.named("test")
    .fromQuery("select itemName from `Dataset.sampletable`").usingStandardSql());



List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("category").setType("STRING"));
TableSchema schema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);

data.apply(BigQueryIO.Write.named("Write").to("Dataset.dataflow_test")
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));

p.run();
```

}

Error code:

```
(6093f22a86dc3c25): Workflow failed. Causes: (6093f22a86dc389a): S01:test/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeRead+Write/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIOWrite/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeWrite failed., (709b1cdded98b0f6): BigQuery creating dataset "_dataflow_temp_dataset_10172746300453557418" in project "1234-project" failed., (709b1cdded98b191): BigQuery execution failed., (709b1cdded98b22c): Error:
 Message: IAM setPolicy failed for 42241429167:_dataflow_temp_dataset_10172746300453557418
 HTTP Code: 400
```

I can imagine that maybe writing it immediately after reading can be a reason for this failing. Therefore I would like to know a good solution for this.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to match the error message. In the code, you are writing to "Dataset.dataflow_test", but the error seems to be writing to a temporary dataset. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: There should be no problem reading from BigQuery and writing back immediately. The first step performed is BigQuery exporting files to Cloud Storage, then these files are read and processed by the Dataflow workers and written back to BigQuery.

In addition to Ben's comment: One error I can see in your code already is that the output TableSchema does not match the TableRows you are writing. You might want to rename `itemName` to `category` in your SQL query, or rename the `category` field to `itemName` in you TableSchema definition. This might however be only one of the problems.

Comment: Thanks for helpful information